# Which one is faster and why?

Tags: performance, haskell

```
(n >= 3 ) && (n <= 99)
```

OR

```
 n `elem` [3..99]
```

Which one is faster and why?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The first one is faster

```
 (n >= 3) && (n <= 99)
```

it is doing 3 operations

```
 n >= 3
 n <= 99
 and
```

Where as the [elem](http://www.zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/elem_f.html) is looking up the item in the array, so is doing upto (99 - 3) * 2 operations.

```
index = 0
isFound = false
array[] = { 3, 4, 5, 6, ... 98, 99 }

while isFound == false
   isFound = (n == array[index++])
```

Comment: Is this how `elem` is actually implemented? Is there really no black magic?? at all?? :)

Comment: What "black magic" would you expect? Even if under the hood the compiler recognises [3..99] is a range and preformed a range check it would still only be the same as (n >= 3) && (n <= 99)

Comment: I'm guessing that you could get GHC to optimize this particular case by using a rewrite rule a la `"elem/enumFromTo" forall x lo hi. elem x (enumFromTo lo hi) = (x >= lo && x <= hi)`. I've never done anything with rewrite rules though (too much like black magic ;-), so take this with a big pinch of salt!

Comment: So I conclude that there is NO black magic! ;)) +1A I like answers with code.

Comment: I thought `elem` would perform `(n >= start) && (n <= end)` check first and then use `step`,`start`,`end` i.e. `[start,start+step,start+2*step...end]` to find if `n` falls into the range or not.

Comment: I mean `(n - start )/ step` is integer and is less than  `(end-start)/step`

Comment: Well, `elem` has no way of knowing what list it's used on: in particular, the information that it comes from an expression like `[3..99]` is gone at runtime. 

Think about how to compute `elem n (3 : 4 : 50000 : [6..99]` and you'll see that elem has to go through all the elements.

As for the question in your first comment: see the source of Data.List : http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/src/GHC-List.html#elem for the definition (it doesn't involve arrays)

Answer (score 11):

(n >= 3) && (n <= 99) is faster as it involves only two trivial comparisons. If the compiler/interpreter does not do any kind of real black magic optimization it has to construct the list ([3..99]) because lazy evaluation cannot be used (normally "pulling" the next value until you're done, which would have a complexity of O(n/2) in this case).

Comment: +1 So there is no black magic though I was expecting some :) also welcome to SO!

Answer (score 8):

These two expressions don't mean the same thing. A subtle difference is that one relies on `Ord` and the other on `Enum`:

```
> :t \n -> (n >= 3) && (n <= 99)
\n -> (n >= 3) && (n <= 99) :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> Bool

> :t \n -> n `elem` [3..99]
\n -> n `elem` [3..99] :: (Num a, Enum a) => a -> Bool
```

So, for example, if n is 3.14159, then the first test will pass, but the second won't:

```
> (pi >= 3) && (pi <= 99)
True

> pi `elem` [3..99]
False
```

Further, while the four Prelude `Num` instances (`Int`, `Integer`, `Float`, and `Double`) are all instances of both `Ord` and `Enum`, it is possible to imagine a numeric type that is an instance of `Ord` but not `Enum`. In such a case, then the second test wouldn't even be legal.

Hence, in general, the compiler can't optomize the second to be as fast as the first unless it knows for a given type, that it is `Ord` and that all ordered values in the range are also in the list enumeration created by `enumFromTo`. For `Float` and `Double` this isn't true, and for `Int` and `Integer` there is no way for the compiler to derive it, the compiler and library programmers would have to hand code it and ensure it held in all cases.

Answer (score -2):

Depends on the machine and compiler (or interpreter).